Powering 5 V mini fan through laptop USB?
I recently bought some 5 V fans, which are super small, they work well with a battery and Arduino 5 V power supply, but when I connect it directly to the USB port in my laptop, it does not work. But the same USB can turn on a few LEDs in series. [I have a USB cable with pins on another end to test LEDs and smaller items using laptop power].
Why does this happen? Should I add any components to make it work? I tried diodes, but still, it's not working through the laptop USB.
I want the fan to run with laptop USB power. I tried using a USB cable to power it up, one end is USB and the other end is jumper pins.
The same works with LEDs, but not with my 5 V mini fan.

What is the current used by an LED, vs the fans? What is the maximum current your laptop usb ports supply?

To which USB port you are connecting, Type-A or Type-C? How are you connecting to it and are you sure you use the correct connector pins or wires for the power supply? How much current the fan draws, what is the rating it has? Does it work if you connect it to a USB phone charger or USB power bank instead of computer USB? Is it a USB2 or USB3 port?

I did not try it with a USB adapter, but I tried it with Arduino, it works well, by small fan I mean it's a 3cm by 3cm fan, used for SMD IC cooling.
I'm unable to measure the current consumption, but I'm sure it draws much less current than 5 LEDs, we used a 5v battery to power the LEDs, the battery was able to run 5 LEDs turned on for around 40 min, the fan was running for 1.2hrs, with the same type battery, both were fully charged.
The fan works with every mode, except my laptop USB, I tried with my friend's PC, still it's not rotating.

I have a cooling pad with two big fans, those two run from the same USB power provided by my laptop.

Many laptops have power limits on their USB sockets. motors take a lot of current to start.

I have a cooling pad with two big fans, and those two run from the same USB power provided by my laptop, the cooling pad has an SMD circuit, I would like to replicate it, but it's extremely tiny and completely SMD board.

It's a "soft-start" circuit, it should be possible to get an equivalent
